# Converting 1-dimensional double value to 2-dimensional double value

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping

I am trying to map the items in 1-dimensional `double[]` to 2-dimensional `double[][]`, in a way that it is arranged in a matrix. For example, `[1, 2, 3, 4]` would be converted into a 2*2 array with `[1, 2]` in the first row and then `[3, 4]` in the second row. No values are given, so I need to put the variables instead of the actual integers, though.

How do I do this?

I tried pushing and slicing, but they only work for `int` not `double`.

Comment: There is no `double` datatype in JavaScript which as the tag on your question suggests is the language you are using. Is it possible you're writing Java code? Please tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo) to map the x index and a simple division to map the y index of the two-dimensional array two the one-dimensional index.

The solution initializes the array with zeroes first. Time and memory complexity would obviously be `Θ(xy)`.

```js
function reshape(oneDimArray, x, y) {
  if(x < 0 || y < 0) throw new RangeError(`x and y must not be negative`)
  const twoDimArray = [...new Array(y)].map(_ => {
    const array = new Array(x);
    array.fill(0, 0, array.length);
    return array;
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < oneDimArray.length; i++) {
    const yIndex = Math.floor(i / x);
    const xIndex = i % x;
    twoDimArray[yIndex][xIndex] = oneDimArray[i];
  }
  return twoDimArray;
}

const sample = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(reshape(sample, 2, 2));
console.log(reshape(sample, 2, 4));
console.log(reshape(sample, 1, 4));
console.log(reshape(sample, 3, 4));
```

```css
/* StackOverflow snippet: console should overlap rendered HTML area */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The same algorithm implemented in Java would look like this:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var sample = new double[]{ 1d, 2d, 3d, 4d };
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(reshape(sample, 2, 2)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(reshape(sample, 2, 4)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(reshape(sample, 1, 4)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(reshape(sample, 3, 4)));
    }

    public static double[][] reshape(double[] oneDimArray, int x, int y)
    {
        if(x < 0 || y < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x and y must not be negative");
        var twoDimArray = new double[y][x];
        for (var i = 0; i < oneDimArray.length; i++) {
            var yIndex = (int)(i / x);
            var xIndex = i % x;
            twoDimArray[yIndex][xIndex] = oneDimArray[i];
        }
        return twoDimArray;
    }
}
```